# How to make jQuery Mobile to display two-lines label (or, in general, to preserve HTML content of a button's label) in a Button component

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It seems that by default jQuery Mobile strips the HTML content of a `<button>` tag.

So for instance placing a `<br/>` tag does not work.

Comment: Please add some code, or at the very least an example of your issue. This question is tempting to close it due to extreme lack of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Right, then don't use one ;-) So instead of :

```
<button>testing<br/>new<br/>lines</button>
```

Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button">testing<br/>new<br/>lines</a>
```

Will achieve same effect - JQM will make it a button and center the text horizontally, and whatever HTML tags you have in there as well.

Hope this helps!